# SQL Server 2012 SSDT "The project could not be deployed to .... A connection cannot be made ...."

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm a newbie to SQL Server 2012. Here is my condition.

I have a running SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence SP1. The problem is I cannot deploy a project to my SSAS from another computer.

The error is:

> The project could not be deployed to the 'DATABASE-SERVER\MSSQLSERVER' server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.  To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.

The following is the things that I've tried:

1. Check the target name on Project > Properties > Deployment > Target server.
2. Check the server service --> all SQL Server services are running.
3. The project can be deployed from server.
4. The connection to server is clear
5. I can connect to the Database Engine and Analysis Service from another computer from SQL Server Management Studio.

Please help me to fix this problem, I've been search for many days for this problem.

Thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Best regards, Stella.

Comment: What happens when you right-click the project in visual studio 2012 and choose "deploy"? From that modal box, you should be able to configure your connections. You also need elevated permission on your target server (not just the ability to connect) since VS will create a deploy script and execute it at the target under your login.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question.No modal box was appeared, the project just run the process until that error is appear (again).

Comment: I am having the same problem and I have tried the same steps.
If you have found the solution to your question kindly post it here.
Thanks

Comment: @SSMA have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the solution was to explicitly specify login information on the Impersonation Information tab on the Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I had the same issue and I reckon more will run into this buzz saw.

My problem was that the remote installation of SSAS did not have an Inbound firewall rule for SSAS application; msmdsrv.exe.

Resolution:
Log on to the server running SSAS as Administrator
Launch Windows Firewall and advanced Security
Add Inbound Rule, give it a meaningful name like SQL Server - SSAS
Action: Allow the connection
On Program and Services Tab: For 'This Program' use Browse and identify msmdsrv.exe
For SQL Server 2014, it is by default here:
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.SQLSVR14\OLAP\bin\msmdsrv.exe 
(Very similar for 2012 and 2016, the numbers are different)
Click OK; You should see a green dot with check mark
Try your project again; It should connect, did for me.

NOTE: If this also work for you, consider going back to the Inbound Rule and consider adding connection restrictions for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by right clicking my data source (under Data Sources in Solution Explorer) → Edit in the General tab → In Connection Manager, do two things:

1. Change **Server name** from localhost to your computer name
2. Use SQL Server Authentication as **Authentication**, as opposed to Windows Authentication, and proceed to enter your user name and password (the "sa" password you use for SSMS).